# How can I print to QTextEdit to mimic printing to console? (Python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.3

I have a piece of code that displays a Gui which has a QTextEdit Field. I would like to print to this field in real time similar to how the print function outputs to the console.

I have tried using multiple instances of the append function. Ex:

```
self.textEdit.append(_translate("MainWindow", ">>> Text", None))
```

The problem is that no matter where they are in the code, they seem to only show after the program is executed. My goal is to have them show in line like the print function does on the console.

I feel like this is an easy answer, but I have had no luck searching.. I am fairly new to Python and any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as mata mentioned the freezing comes from doing all your work in the same (main) thread, which also handles UI updates. One way to solve your responsiveness issue is indeed to frequently use QApplication.processEvents() in your blocking code. That will give the impression of a responsive GUI to the user if frequent enough.

However, using threads in Python (whether native or QThread) will not always work. That is because of the existence of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL, [the wiki has a good short intro](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)). In short, Python does not allow more than one thread to execute code at the same time.

If your background task is light, or is based on IO, you can get around this as most IO-heavy modules for Python release the GIL while doing their job. However, if you are performing heavy computations in Python, the GIL will be locked by your processes, and as such your UI will still be unresponsive.

Consider the following example, built using PySide:

```
import sys, random
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from urllib import urlopen
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    update_signal = QtCore.Signal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.progress_bar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress_bar.setRange(0, 10)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.progress_bar)
        self.update_signal[int].connect(self.progress_bar.setValue)
        self.show()
        self.t = Thread(target=self.worker)
        self.t.start()

    def worker(self):
        while self.progress_bar.value() < 10:
            self.update_signal.emit(self.progress_bar.value()+1)
            print "Starting Sleep"
            sleep(5)
            print "End of Sleep"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qapp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(qapp.exec_())
```

Then, try replacing the worker function to:

```
def worker(self):
    while self.progress_bar.value() < 10:
        self.update_signal.emit(self.progress_bar.value()+1)
        v = 0
        print "Starting Add"
        for i in xrange(5000000):
            v = v+random.uniform(0, 100)
        print "End of Add"
```

The first case maintains a responsive UI, as the call to sleep() releases the GIL. But the second example does not, as the computationally-intense algorithm keeps the lock.

One solution could be using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package. 
From the docs:

> multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an
>   API similar to the threading module. The multiprocessing package
>   offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping
>   the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads.
>   Due to this, the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully
>   leverage multiple processors on a given machine.

[A simple, illustrative example of using python multipocessing.](http://timothyawiseman.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/a-really-simple-multiprocessing-python-example/)

Also, if you have further interest, [this blog post about multi-processing techniques](http://doughellmann.com/2007/10/multiprocessing.html) might be of interest.

Comment: You are right. I was doing everything in one file. I am very new to python and it is still growing on me. I just wanted to make a productivity tool for my job. I am not sure if my background task is "light". Could you assist me in determining this? I am taking an IP and port and wirelessly(cellular) pulling a file from a machine. This file is typically an excel file and can take anywhere from 10 seconds to 10 minutes to download. I just want to let the user know when it starts and when it is finished.

Comment: I am not sure about your specific method of getting data, but network I/O is non-blocking, so you can safely use threads in your case. Try replacing the code in the while loop in the above example with your request code and you will see that the UI stays responsive.

Comment: When I try to run the code above, I get the popup and the 'Start Sleep' then an immediate message that python has stopped responding. When I close python the End Sleep message appears. I am using python 3.3.. I think that shouldnt matter (I fixed the print statements). With the second, Same error (python stopped) but Neither print is displayed. Just a message that says QWidget::repaint: recursive repaint detected. Any idea what this is? (p.s. thanks for this help. The program I am making will save me hours at my job)

Comment: You're right, my bad, tried to update the value of the progressbar directly. Edited the answer to use signals and slots. Should be ok now.

Comment: you don't want to mix multiprocess and QT.

Comment: Signals and slots are another new aspect of python for me.. I had to change the from PySide with from PyQt4 and just import urllib directly to get past the beginning issues. Now I am getting an error that is saying 'module' object has no attribute 'signal'... I think this might mean that I need another import but I am most likely incorrect. Any advice on the matter?

Comment: @LtWorf  Do you have an alternate suggestion of how I can solve the issue at hand?

Comment: Nop, I'd try QThread. I tried using multiprocess with qt a few days ago and the program would crash with very strange errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am very new to python so I have a lot of learning to do yet. I think I might leave the program exporting to the command prompt until I can do some more research with threads. Thanks for the help everyone! I appreciate the kindness of strangers!

Answer (score 2):

This means that you're probably doing all your work in the GUI thread. This is a common mistake, and it means that the GUI will freeze and not respond while there is something else going on.

You can add a call to `QApplication.processEvents()` to allow for the GUI to update after you change the text in your `QTextEdit`, but that will only partially solve the problem, the GUI will nevertheless freeze up between those calls.

The solution is simple: do the work in a separate thread. You should read [Threading Basics](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html) from the Qt documentation, that should get you started.